# Как расположить элементы?

Tags: android, xml

Здравствуйте.Я начинающий android developer. Не могу расположить элементы так как я хочу.Они отказываются стоять так. Например,хочу расположить на самом верху TextView(где будет вопрос),ниже два Button'a(которые будут показывать предыдущий или следующий вопрос), и ниже 4 кнопки,расположенные 2x2(варианты ответа).Как это сделать?

Comment: как вы пытались это сделать. Приложите разметку. Еще желательно рисунок, как бы вы хотели, чтобы выглядело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отступы сами проставьте какие надо

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Вопрос"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text="Предыдущий"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:text="Следующий"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text="Ответ А"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:text="Ответ В"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text="Ответ С"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:text="Ответ D"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

можно вот так:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="example"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow> 
        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button1"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="example1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="example2"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="example3"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="example4"/>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

этот пример в качестве общего наброска, и требует дополнительных атрибутов, которые вы уж сами допишите как вам нужно